# How to lock and synchronize update of primes[] and total?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, locks

I tried to make start, N final then, initialize them, then use lock for primes[total], total, but however Netbeans keep showing error that start, N is not initialized, so the problem is how to initialize final variables? (There is also main method but I havnt posted to keep the question short)

```
public class PrimeBuggy implements Runnable {
//private static int start, N;
//I changed above line to following:
private final int start,N;
private static int numThreads;
private static int primes[];
private static boolean pflag[];
private static int total = 0;
//I created a lock
private Lock lock();
this.start = start;
this.N = N;
private static boolean is_prime(int v) {
    int i;
    int bound = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt((double)v)) + 1;
    for (i = 2; i < bound; i++) {
        if (pflag[i])
            continue;
        if (v % i == 0) {
            pflag[v] = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (v > 1);
}    

/***/
private int threadNum;
private PrimeBuggy(int threadNum) { this.threadNum = threadNum; }
public void run() {
    int i;
    //lock this begining
    lock.lock();
    start = N/numThreads * threadNum;
    N = start + N/numThreads;
    for (i = start; i < N; i++) {
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            primes[total] = i;
            total++;
            //unlock at the end
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are many problems in this code and one of them is unlock() in the loop.

Comment: I know, I screwed up somewhere understanding locks and synchronization. My variables are shared but I want them local.

Comment: @ProgrammingQueen what tigran means is that you are unlocking prematurely. Also simply use a constructor  PrimeBuggy(int N) and initialize the N with it.

Answer (score 0):

if a field is final, then you have to initialize it when it's declared or with a constructor:

```
   private final int N =10;

   private PrimeBuggy(int threadNum) {

       start = N/numThreads * threadNum;
       this.threadNum = threadNum;
   }
```

Nevertheless, you have in your code several initialization in a methid:

```
    start = N/numThreads * threadNum;
    N = start + N/numThreads;
```

and this makes no sense at all:

```
    //I created a lock
    private Lock lock();
    this.start = start;
    this.N = N;
```